# Prevalence of anatomical cause for a lateral epicondylitis

Tags: epicondylitis, statistics

I wonder how frequently a lateral epicondylitis has an anatomical cause. When searching for the information, I couldn't find any specific numbers, and the information I read was ranging from "there is often an anatomical problem" to "[it is a ] rare cause". Obviously it may depend on the age of the individual, and other factors. If so, assume a 25 year-old individual (though I am curious about other ages as well).

---

Below are some references, sorted by how frequent the anatomical cause is, descending order.

[Holston Valley Medical Center](https://www.wellmont.org/uploadedFiles/Hospitals/Facilities/Tendonitis.pdf):

> Anatomical Problem: Tendons in the human body are like a bundle of
>   rubber bands. These rubber bands function best when they are all
>   parallel to each other. Most often, tendonitis affects the alignment
>   of the fibers, or band-like structures, of the tendon. Instead of
>   presenting with fibers aligned parallel, many of the fibers are
>   crossed. The crossing of the fibrous structures of the tendon causes
>   the muscle and tendon to operate at a disadvantage, which causes the
>   body to experience pain and inflammation. Therefore, **there is often an
>   anatomical problem with the tendon underlying tendonitis**.

[Tendon Disorders Organization](http://tendondisorders.org/whats-really-wrong.html)

> **Often, there is an anatomical cause for tendon disorders** - some people just have a problem with the way they are built or the way they move...and that needs to be addressed

[Yale University](http://www.yale.edu/ergo/tendonitis.html):

> **Sometimes, there is an anatomical cause for tendonitis**. If the tendon does not have a smooth path to glide along, it will be more likely to become irritated and inflamed. In these unusual situations, surgical treatment may be necessary to realign the tendon.

[Sachin R Shenoy MD](http://www.drshenoy.com/tendonitis.html):

> Anatomical cause of tendonitis: 
>   **Anatomy is a rare cause of tendonitis**. If the tendon does not have a smooth surface area in which to work against it will often become inflamed and irritated quite easily. In these situations surgery is often required to rectify the problem.